# iMac 27" 14,2 late 2013 CPU upgrade

Tags: imac, upgrade, macos, cpu

I recently brought an iMac 27" 14,2 back to life after a CPU fault (which  in itself was odd since I never seen a PC or Mac with a fried Intel CPU) and it runs pretty nice ... but on a Intel Core i3 4130 which leaves a lot to desire in terms of performance.

i'm thinking of replacing it with an i5 or i7 - but then I've seen that Xeon 2013 Xeon's are quite cheap and was wondering if the iMac Mainboard can run with it.

**Does anybody knows if such upgrade is possible?** 
E3 1150 Xeon's are basically i7s without the GPU but more cache and offer better per watt performance.

---

**Update**

I will test 3 different CPU's with the iMac 27 14,2 mainboard, *despite* the the answer below. The information I found is not conclusive and well... why not?

I was able to grab 3 CPU's for testing, however the 1285 is not something you can call **cheap** alternative to i7 ;-)

- Xeon E3-1231v3
- Xeon E3-1285v3
- Core i7 4790K

Once tested I'll share the results here, incl. some pictures. The CPU cooling block CPU/GPU hybrid is quite **difficult** to mount and one need to be really careful with it -  something ifixit and others don't mention.

Comment: Will you really notice a better "per watt" performance on a large desktop like that - even if the upgrade was possible, which Allan has pointed out isn't?

Comment: Can you post a specific xeon you have in mind? I can't seem to find one that can either rival 4771's 3.9GHz or meaningfully undercut it's 84W power budget. (skimming 4W hardly counts, shutting down the GPU likely saves more).

Comment: Take this one for example: https://ark.intel.com/products/80910/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1231-v3-8M-Cache-3_40-GHz

Comment: If I had to choose between Core i7 and Xeon - I would pick Xeon, but you are right, anything less ~10W won't really matter.

Answer (score 8):

It will not work with a Xeon processor.

The CPU you should get is anything from the Haswell line of CPUs.  If I were doing the upgrade, I would install an Core i7 (4771).

Comment: Are you absoulute sure about that? I want to try this CPU https://ark.intel.com/products/80910/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1231-v3-8M-Cache-3_40-GHz

Comment: If I am not mistaken, a Xeon processor needs ECC memory.  1)  those are few and far between in SO-DIMM form factor and 2), there's no documentation stating that the iMac will support this type of memory.

Comment: You are mistaken, ECC memory is optional, all motherboards and processors support non ECC unbuffered ram.

Comment: What you can't do is mix ECC with non-ECC, since that can't work. Unbuffered ECC is actually slower then Unbuffered non-ECC DIMM's (which is confusing since one would think it's the other way around when ECC is done through CPU cache) - so if you are not running a rendering farm - you won't care a lot about ECC, and you can run non-ECC DIMM's in Mac Pro, the CPU doesn't care.